# Can I send requests between two endpoints?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Let's say I have those 2 view functions, `vf1` and `vf2`, and I want them to communicate using the `requests` lib something like:

```
@app.route('/vf1')
def vf1():
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/vf2')
    #return r.text
    return 'yeeeey it worked' #obviouly it didn't... yet
```

and then:

```
@app.route('/vf2', methods=['POST','GET'])
def vf2():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return jsonify({'message': 'post msg'})
        else:
            return jsonify({'message': 'get msg'})
    except:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Something went wrong'})
```

This code does not work, the page just keep loading with no error msg or anything, I hope someone can explain why or suggest the right way to do something like that.
Btw both vf1 and vf2 are in the same flask application.

Comment: I do not know Python but generally, things like this are solved by creating a common function/service/helper/util and both endpoints will be working with that common service.

Comment: thanks, apparently my question is indeed duplicated and I found exactly what I needed.